# Python pip failure: Errno 13 on METADATA

Tags: python, powershell, pip, ioerror

I'm using Windows Vista and Windows PowerShell. I've installed Python, setuptools, pip, pil, pillow, et alia.

pip appears to work when I'm logged in as administrator. However, when I log in as a normal user, even `pip list` gets an error; the bottom of the trace is:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.49-py2.7.egg\pkg_resources.py", line 1353, in _getstream = open(path, 'rb')<br>
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\\python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-1.5.2.dist-info\\METADATA'
```

1. `METADATA` was read-only; I've tried removing the read-only restriction, but the error doesn't change.
2. The `open()` command is `"rb"` ("read binary"), anyway, so the normal read-only lock should be fine.

Any ideas?  This is blocking exercise 8 of Tango with Django (which requires PIL's Image class).

Comment: Check the permissions on `c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.5.2.dist-info\METADATA` ("Security" tab in the folder's properties dialog). You may need to grant your user write permission to the folder.

Comment: Thanks, but I've already given write permission to the entire site-packages folder (that folder and everything underneath).  The problem persists.

Comment: Check if another process is keeping a open handle on `c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.5.2.dist-info\METADATA`. You can do this with [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) or [`handle`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655).

Comment: Thanks.  Process Explorer will be a very useful tool for me.  However, it shows that there is no open handle for METADATA.  I also tried rebooting the system, and the problem is still here.

Comment: I have an extra datum: I *can* run pip as administrator.
Any ideas for how to proceed?
Thanks again.

Comment: With the information you provided that's all I can tell from the distance. Sorry.